# node-pre-gyp not accessible from fsevents

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am getting the following error when deploying my container

```
#15 1.066 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp not accessible from fsevents
#15 1.076
#15 1.076 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#15 1.076 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-11T11_40_13_120Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm ci]: exit code: 1
```

following is my dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm ci
RUN npm audit
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=0 /app/dist /app
COPY ./__docker_content_start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD /start.sh
```

I am unable to find a solution for this. Any help appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `node-pre-gyp` as a dependency to your `package.json`

```
npm i --save node-pre-gyp
```